# Command line program for jailbroken iOS dies in iPad but not in iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cross-compiling, jailbreak

I'm trying to build a command line program to run in the terminal of jailbroken iOS devices.

To keep it simple I tested with a simple hello world:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

Which I build with:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/ main.c -o hello
```

The generated executable works fine in an iPhone 3G running iOS 4.2.1, but in an iPad running 4.3.5 it outputs:

```
Killed: 9
```

Both are jailbroken, and can run apps from Cydia just fine.

I tried debugging directly on the iPad with gdb from Cydia, but gdb exits when the program receives the kill signal.

For what it's worth, the program I'm really trying to build is [Ledger](http://ledger-cli.org/). I have it running on my iPhone 3G, but when I tried it on the iPad it fails as above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [theos](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started). It makes building anything for jailbroken devices really easy. I believe you can use the tool template for a command-line application.

Comment: Thanks! Theos worked and also led me to what the problem was. The step that was missing was signing the executable, seems like the iPhone 3G doesn't check that the code is signed. I now found this article by Saurik that explains it: http://www.saurik.com/id/8

Comment: Yeah, code signing can be tricky. Another reason why theos is so great, it does it all for you.

Comment: The templates don't have a command-line option. The closest I found was a tweak and the result of a make package is a .deb package that I don't know how to run after installing. How do I just make a simple binary executable?

Answer (score 3):

You must either self signed the app either use `ldid -S` to fool the iOS loader.

`ldid` is available on command line on the iPhone itself.  There is also a Mac OS X binary available here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3157793/ldid .

Another option is to install iOSOpenDev tools which will install all this by default, on top of Xcode

Answer (score 2):

[iOSOpenDev](http://iOSOpenDev.com) extends Xcode and provides project templates for iOS development like command-line tools that you're trying to create along with handling code-signing and Debian package creation for Cydia. Worth a look; can be easier than Theos for some.

Answer (score -1):

Please codesign the app and then install it .. it will run